# Confusion in class loading styles

Tags: java

As I found in one thread [Java: Difference between Class.forName and ClassLoader.loadClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345220/java-difference-between-class-forname-and-classloader-loadclass) that **Class.forName() will always use the ClassLoader of the caller, whereas ClassLoader.loadClass() can specify a different ClassLoader**

```
System.out.println(Class.forName("test.Employee").getClassLoader());
System.out.println(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("test.Employee").getClassLoader());
```

But above two lines are printing the same result

```
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ced01
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ced01
```

Please explain the reason.

Comment: Why do expect the result to be different?

Comment: if the classloaders are different in both styles then there should be two different objects.

Comment: load the classes using different class loaders and compare the class objects (not class instances) for equality.. You will get your answer

Comment: @WhoAmI my question is not for Employee class object equality, It's for classloader's object.

Comment: In both the cases? then what is caller's class loader?

Comment: @DeepakTiwari you can add classloaders. Afterwards both methods can start to differ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference betweeen Loading a class using ClassLoader and Class.forName](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285855/difference-betweeen-loading-a-class-using-classloader-and-class-forname)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference for you as your current class was loaded using the SystemClassLoader wich happens to be `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7ced01`.

If you use a different classloader to load a class, both aproaches will use different classloaders when used in that class you loaded with a different classloader.