# Java this class loader vs classForName

Tags: java

Does this two Java statement lookup the class in the same way?

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("Foo");
```

and

```
Class.forName("Foo");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class.forName() vs ClassLoader.loadClass() - which to use for dynamic loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100376/class-forname-vs-classloader-loadclass-which-to-use-for-dynamic-loading)

Comment: By **"lookup"**, do you mean loading the class?

Comment: By lookup i mean the sources that are try to load the class

Comment: ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() can be different from the class classLoader, the class invoking it can be loaded from a custom class loader.

Comment: In your case, the second one, under the hood, uses the first one. Is that what you were trying to know?

Comment: Yes gurung that is what i want to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're different: even though they use the same class loader (see `forName()` [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)) `loadClass()` does not run static initializers while `forName()` does.

This is easily demonstrated with the following classes:

```
public class ClassA {
  static {
    System.out.println("ClassA static initializer");
  }

  public ClassA() {}
}
```

and

```
public class ClassB {
  private ClassB() {}

  private void loadStuff(boolean initialize) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if (initialize) {
      Class.forName("ClassA");
    } else {
      this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("ClassA");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ClassB b = new ClassB();
    b.loadStuff(true); // Try also false
  }
}
```

Running `ClassB` passing true to `loadStuff()` will display "ClassA static initializer" while running it passing false to `loadStuff()` doesn't display anything.

Of course, if you subsequently instantiate the loaded class its static initializer will be run if it has not yet been executed. In this case the difference between the two methods of loading a class is in the time when static initializers are run.

Answer (score -1):

Here is interesting discussion on this topic. 
[Class.forName() vs ClassLoader.loadClass() - which to use for dynamic loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100376/class-forname-vs-classloader-loadclass-which-)
to-use-for-dynamic-loading