# ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, tomcat7

Super new to JSP and just trying to access mysql

```
public static Connection connect(){
try{
    Class.forName("con.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name", "root", "******");
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new Error(e);
}
```

I continue to get this error: ClassNotFoundException: con.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I understand that I need to change the "classpath" and/or that I need to move the mysql-connector jar file to tomcat7/lib but I have 2 problems:

1. I have absolutely no idea what the classpath is and how to change it using ubuntu and dreamweaver.
2. my tomcat7 folder doesn't have a lib directory. I don't know where to put the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the jar on your classpath, I think that yuor problem is a misspelt fully qualified classname: `con.mysql.jdbc.Driver` should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a `J2EE` application.  Within the project should be `WEB-INF` directory.  Within that directory, create (if necessary) a lib directory and place the `mysql-connector.jar` file within `lib`.  This will cause the driver to be placed on the runtime classpath.

Also as `Romski` pointed out change the class name to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, however I'm not even sure this code is necessary with newer version of the driver and JDBC.  If your using `Tomcat7` the JDK is most likely recent enough to not require this code.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12933246/714969

Comment: im not using eclipse, I just made a .jsp file and placed it in the tomcat7/webapps/ROOT folder. Should i make a WEB-INF folder? and if so, where should I put it. I am NOT using eclipse btw.

Comment: also removing the class.forname changes the error to: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/bitzooka

Comment: @user2998553 You can make a `WEB-INF\lib` folder in the root of your application.  I think the issues you receive from removing `class.forname` is due to the fact that its not finding the jar on the runtime classpath

Comment: 'No suitable driver' found means that the jar is not on your classpath. Start with a really basic class with a main method and try to load the driver there first and when working, you can move to a webapp. If you don't know how to set the classpath to include the jar, then checkout the Java tutorials.