# What is the difference between java.lang.class<Cls> and just Cls?

Tags: java

What is the difference between `java.lang.class<Cls>` and just `Cls`?

I need to pass this to a function:

```
java.lang.Class<org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.termlist.TermlistRequest>
```

I tried `new TermlistRequest()` but it is this:

```
org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.termlist.TermlistRequest
```

Can you explain what is it in Java? And how to create an object of this type?

---

[java.lang.class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) - what I missed was I needed to append `.class` to `Cls` to get the type `java.lang.class<Cls>`

Comment: You need to learn about reflection.

Comment: We need more context (i.e. more of your code) to understand what concept you are having trouble with.  Show us the definition of the function you want to call.

Comment: The former is an instance of `java.lang.Class`, the latter an instance of whatever class. You can append `.class` to a class name to get its class instance, e.g. `Class<org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.termlist.TermlistRequest> clazz = org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.termlist.TermlistRequest.class;`.

Comment: @Siguza looks like I needed your comment

Comment: To all "-": do I need to learn a language before asking questions about it?

Comment: Before you asked the question did you search for `java.lang.Class` to see what it was? What did you find? What didn't you understand?

Comment: Nobody said any of that. You seem to be curious about the downvotes. When you hover over that button, you'll see that one of the reasons is the lack of research shown in a question. The questions in my previous comment are rhetorical. They are meant to have you edit that information into your question in order to improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `Class<T>` and `T` is that `Class<T>` represents metadata about `T`. You can look up `T`'s methods and fields, and also create new instances by calling [`newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) method.

As far as creating `Class<T>` objects goes, the simplest approach is to use `MyClass.class` syntax, e.g.

```
Class<TermlistRequest> tr = TermlistRequest.class;
```

`Class` (but not `Class<T>`) objects can also be obtained by [resolving classes dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8100376/335858).