# Flow of class loading for a simple program

Tags: java, classloader

I am just now beginning to learn the internal architecture of Java. I have roughly understood the concept of class loading which loads the required classes when `jvm` runs, `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown when a class is not found and specific class loader loads the classes referenced by the class.

Can someone please explain clearly the flow of class loading i.e. the sequence of bootstrap class loading and user-defined class loading in the sample Java code below.

```
import java.io.File;
public class Sample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "sample";
        File file = new File(fileName);
        file.isFile();
    }
}
```

Also I learnt from a reference material that "`classloader` maintains the namespaces of the classes it loads". By namespaces, does that mean the literal names of the class? Also can someone please explain the implication/advantage of that?

Comment: A good resource to get started http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rebel-labs-tutorial-do-you-really-get-classloaders/

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html

Comment: Please just ask one question per question.  The first one was good enough.

Comment: Also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214174/how-is-the-java-bootstrap-classloader-loaded/29562960#29562960

Comment: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html I found this link very helful

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You will run your `Sample` class as follows

`> java Sample`

for little magic, check out the output of`-verbose:class` option and you see tons of following lines..

```
[Opened C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Comparable from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
.
.
.
.
.
.
[Loaded java.security.cert.Certificate from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded Sample from file:/D:/tmp/]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from C:\jdk1.6.0_14\jre\lib\rt.jar]
```

You see a bunch of classes from `\jre\lib\rt.jar` are loaded, much before your class is loaded by `Bootstrap` class loader (or Primordial ). These are the pre-requisite for running any Java program hence loaded by Bootstrap.

Another set of jars is loaded by `Extension` class loader. In this particular example, there was no need of any classes from the lib `\jre\lib\ext` hence its not loaded. But Extension class loader are specifically assigned the task of loading the classes from the extension lib.

**EDIT:** Apart from the standard platform java classes Sun/Oracle also provide a set of jars which are used to **extend the platform's core API**. The jars placed in the extension lib folder are automatically placed in the classpath and hence not needed to be included in classpath explicitly. Here is [nice official article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html) on the same topic.

Finally, your class `Sample` is loaded by `Application` class loader after Bootstrap and Extension have finished loading.

Comment: @Santhosh: thanks..Ur answer suffices but can u still more elaborate on Extension class loader? Its utility is unclear

Comment: @santosh +1 for mentioning the `-verbose:class` option.

Answer (score 51):

### [Classloader hierarchy](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/rebel-labs-tutorial-do-you-really-get-classloaders/2/)

Whenever a new JVM is started the bootstrap classloader is responsible to load key Java classes (from `java.lang` package) and other runtime classes to the memory first. The bootstrap classloader is a parent of all other classloaders. Consequently, it is the only one without a parent.

Next comes the extension classloader. It has the bootstrap classloader as parent and is responsible for loading classes from all `.jar` files kept in the `java.ext.dirs` path–these are available regardless of the JVM’s classpath.

The third and most important classloader from a ***developer’s perspective*** is the system classpath classloader, which is an immediate child of the extension classloader. It loads classes from directories and jar files specified by the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, `java.class.path` system property or `-classpath` command line option.

[image: Classloader hierarchy]

***ClassLoader Namespace***

In Java a class is uniquely identified using 
`ClassLoader + Class` as the same class may be loaded by two different class loaders.

```
Class A loaded by ClassLoader A != Class A loaded by ClassLoader B
```

> How is it helpful?

It is helpful for defining different protection and access policies for different classloaders. Take an example of applet which is loaded using a different classloader, you would not want a third party application all access to your resources. So for security its important to maintain different namespaces.

Comment: this clarifies stuffs to me to a certain extent. can u please answer to my question relating to class loader's name-spaces?

Comment: I have added the explanation. Hope it helps.

Comment: How bootstrap classloader is loaded - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214174/how-is-the-java-bootstrap-classloader-loaded/29562960#29562960

Answer (score 11):

JVM maintains a runtime pool in permgen area where classes are loaded. Whenever a class is referenced default class loader finds the class in the class path and loads it into this pool. And this is not specific to user defined classes or classes provided in JDK. When a class is referenced it is loaded into the memory.

Classes loaded by the ClassLoader are stored internally in the ClassLoader instance

```
// The classes loaded by this class loader. The only purpose of this table
// is to keep the classes from being GC'ed until the loader is GC'ed.
private final Vector<Class<?>> classes = new Vector<>();
```

When class needs to be added to the memory following function is called:

```
// Invoked by the VM to record every loaded class with this loader.
void addClass(Class c) {
    classes.addElement(c);
}
```

Found a useful diagram on how Class Loaders work.

[image]

Comment: you mean to say that - " as long as its class loader exists, the class exists"??

Comment: Yes and ClassLoader instance does not get GCed as it is referenced by JVM thread. Infact that is why even if you have a Singleton class it is possible to create two instances with two different class loaders.

Comment: So.. you mean to say "if I have several hundred classes being loaded by the same classloader, then until the class loader is GCed, the classes will not be GCed"??... How is this efficient?

Comment: Well yes and it is actually JVM specific. The only way that a Class can be unloaded is if the Classloader used is garbage collected. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148681/unloading-classes-in-java for more details.

Comment: @TheLostMind Because classes are rarely referenced once and then never again, and class loading is not necessarily quick. Besides which, classes may be written under the assumption that they are only loaded once per program run, which would be violated if the classes are unloaded and then loaded again. (I don't know if the JLS guarantees this behavior but I've seen it in use.)

Comment: ok... thanks for the info :) .. one more thing... will GC treat class loaders in a different way while doing its operations??.. the above 2 answers imply that there will be no "generation-shift" of classes and all classes will be flagged as "in-use" so that GC doesnt happen on them..

Comment: No ClassLoader instances are same as any other Objects in the heap. The statement that it does not get GCed come from the fact that ClassLoaders have references from JVM threads which run till the java process is completed and JVM shuts down. For eg the BootStrap Class Loader is a native implementation meaning its code is embedded in JVM. So it's reference will always be alive. Hence we say they are not the potential candidates for GC. Other than that GC treats them the same way.

Comment: @TheLostMind I can't say for sure, but the code Aniket posted in the answer implies that the GC treats them no differently; otherwise the classloader wouldn't need to keep a `Vector` around just to prevent garbage collection.

Answer (score 6):

The **Java Virtual Machine** starts up by creating an initial class, which is specified in an implementation-dependent manner, using the bootstrap class loader ([§5.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.1)). The Java Virtual Machine then links the initial class, initializes it and the static instance variables declared in it and finally invokes the **public class method void main(String[])**. The invocation of this method drives all further execution. Execution of the Java Virtual Machine instructions constituting the main method may cause linking (and consequently creation) of additional classes and interfaces, as well as invocation of additional methods.

read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) link

Answer (score 2):

> The loading process can be viewed as interaction between Classloader
>   Subsystem and the Memory Area of JVM.

Classloader works in three general steps 1.) Loading 2.) Linking and 3.) Initialization.

> The very basic interaction between Classloader Subsystem and the
>   Memory Area happens during **Linking** (apart from other interactions!)

Linking activity is subdivided into  i.) Verify ii.) Prepare and iii.) Resolve.
Verify: is more for security, valid compilation is checked.  In the step ii.) Prepare - static variable memory is allocated and assigned with default values.
And in

> iii.) Resolve: Symbolic references are replaced with original
>   references from the "Method Area" which contains class level data and
>   static variables.

[JVM Arch](http://ourjavaguide.blogspot.com/2012/03/jvmjava-virtual-machine-architecture.html)