# Loading of java hotspot classes in jvm

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/jdkfiles.html) describes /jdk1.7.0/jre/lib/rt.jar as bootstrap classes for java runtime, I am curious if these are ever loaded when running a JDK rather than a JRE and if so how these get replaced with hotspot classes at runtime?

For example rt.jar does not appear to contain a class corresponding to hotspot/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java, so if I add a JDK6 version into eclipse as a JDK and step through the following in a debugger:

```
Collections.emptySet().iterator();
```

I get the code corresponding to the rt.jar/java.util.Collections which creates a new iterator instance, wheras the hotspot version from src.zip which pools an empty iterator does not appear to be present.

My understanding has always been that the hotspot code will be what is linked in prior to/during runtime, so I suspect I have just missed the location, but if this is not true how does the hotspot code get linked in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java SE distributions for versions before the [release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Class_Library#Licensing) of the JCL source as part of the OpenJDK [reference](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=336) implementation have differences between their src.zip (with the corresponding compiled classes in rt.jar), and the [backported](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk6-dev/2008-February/000001.html) OpenJDK 6 source code that is [available online](https://web.archive.org/web/20180428174841/http://grepcode.com:80/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.emptySet()).

The reason is that changes from OpenJDK 7, such as the that pooled iterator, may be backported into OpenJDK 6 versions without the corresponding change being made in *any* Java SE 6 version, as illustrated by this SCM diagram from the [OpenJDK 6 project](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk6/):

[image]

As Arkantos mentioned, the Bootstrap ClassLoader will [load rt.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796046/flow-of-class-loading-for-a-simple-program/20796420#20796420), including the Collections.class with the non-pooled iterator in Java SE 6 distributions.

Answer (score 1):

All Java programs need JRE to run. Even JDK has a sub folder `jre` inside it. JDK is for the developers to write,compile,profile java programs. All the classes from `java.lang` and `java.util` are present inside rt.jar(shortcut for run-time) which will be loaded on every java program execution by the Bootstrap ClassLoader.

`src.zip` is the source code for Java SE APIs, it doesn't include hot spot source code/ VM code and several other things written in C/C++ but it's open to download for everyone.

I just compared the `java.util.Collections.emptySet().iterator()` in JAVA_HOME/`src.zip` and in `JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar` and found them to be same.

Comment: Thanks for the details, you didn't say which version of java you did the comparison in? I upvoted you for the reference to the Bootstrap Class Loader, but as I had to do my own research to fully answer my own question, I have posted that as an answer instead.

Comment: I compared those files in my local which is having jdk8u25