# Where the instance variables and instance methods are stored in java?

Tags: java, memory-management

In the below program,  does it mean that 3 instance variables and 3 instance methods are created and memory is allocated to them ?

```
class Foo{

    String name = "";

   public void greet(String name){

        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Greetings {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

    Foo ob = new Foo();
    Foo ob1 = new Foo();
    Foo ob2 = new Foo();

    ob.greet("hello friends");
    ob1.greet("welcome to java");
    ob2.greet("let us learn");
    System.out.println(ob.name);
    System.out.println(ob1.name);
    System.out.println(ob2.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796046/flow-of-class-loading-for-a-simple-program

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification does not say anything about how memory is organized, or how objects, methods, and classes are represented.

So, the answer is: you can't and *shouldn't* know.

Answer (score 0):

All the 3 objects are stored in a heap memory. The size of the heap increases decreases as the application runs. The **new** operator here allocates memory to the object in the heap. Which means each time you say **new** in the statement a separate memory space is allocated to that object in the heap The methods are stored in JVM internal heap.

you can find a simple example of how memory is managed for objects in java [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31755&seqNum=8)

Comment: There is nothing in the Java Language Specification that says anything about where objects are stored, how memory is managed, or even that there is a heap at all. In fact, most modern mainstream high-performance Java implementations, will perform Escape Analysis and/or Escape Detection and can prove that no reference escapes the local scope and will allocate everything on the stack in this example. A sophisticated implementation may even be able to prove that there are no side-effects and inline and optimize everything into just three static calls to `println` with constant strings.