# How to hot swap java.lang Class in Java

Tags: java, jvm, javassist, hotswap

I know it's not a good demand. But I need to do that now.

I need to replace the method of `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)`

But `ClassLoader.preDefineClass(String , ProtectionDomain)` checks whether the class name of the full name starts with `java.`, and if so, throws an exception and is not allowed to load.

Is there a way to bypass **runtime** security checks instead of **compile time**?

## Update

The real requirement is that many older projects need to migrate to new environments, because some of these projects may be out of date and some of them may not be able to find the source code. I am required to simulate the old environment in a new environment so that these ancient projects can continue to function.

## Upadte (GhostCat)

I tried the way which you given.

### ClassLoader Class

```
public class ClassLoaderTest extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
        System.out.println("getResourceAsStream " + name);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[]{1, 3, 5, 7, 9});
    }
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Load class " + name);
        String fileName = name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) + ".class";
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

        if (is == null) {
            return super.loadClass(name);
        }

        byte[] b = new byte[0];
        try {
            b = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(b);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return defineClass(name, b, 0, b.length);
    }
}
```

### Invoke Class

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    ClassLoaderTest classLoaderTest = new ClassLoaderTest();
    Class clazz = Class.forName("com.Client", true, classLoaderTest);
    Object client = clazz.newInstance();
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("method");
    method.invoke(client);
}
```

### Client Class

```
public class Client {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("aaa"));
        System.out.println(Class.class.getResourceAsStream("bbb"));
        System.out.println("".getClass().getResourceAsStream("ccc"));
    }
}
```

It really works with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)`, but `Class.class.getResourceAsStream(String)` / `"".getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)` . Because I cannot load class using my custom ClassLoader which
 name start with `java.`

Comment: This is disabled due to security considerations. you can extend the class needed and call your own class if needed, but replacement as such is not possible.

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need to replace `Class.getResourceAsStream()`? That's what your question should be about.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, it's really my question. Because a very old project has migrated to a new environment, the old project has long been without maintenance and is now trying to simulate an environment consistent with the old project.

Comment: @RishiGoel Thanks.It's a very old project, but it's practically useless, but it's not willing to throw it away. I guess a part of the project may have been unable to find the source code

Comment: What is `ClassLoader.preDefineClass(String, ProtectionDomain)`? There is no such method.

Comment: @Holger It's a private method. However, it looks like he's going to have to come up with a different clever way to finish the migration.

Comment: @Kayaman: then, I don’t see the relevance here. If it’s `private`, it’s a method that `ClassLoader` will invoke itself, but can’t be changed (doing so would imply that changing `ClassLoader` is already changed).

Comment: @Holger This method is called in `ClassLoader.defineClass(String , byte[] , int , int ,ProtectionDomain)`, which is mandatory. In fact, this is not necessary, this method is only a security check.

Comment: Well, throwing an exception for `java.*` classes is within [the contract of `defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-): “*Throws: …
SecurityException - … if name begins with "java."*”. So it’s irrelevant, which `private` methods are involved.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

This class gets loaded by the [bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214174/how-is-the-java-bootstrap-classloader-loaded) class loader. And you can't change what this guy is doing - it is written in *native* code. In other words: this is at the core of the JVM - and you are not allowed to tamper with that.

That is the "whole idea" of that the java security concept: the user can't "get" into things that are guaranteed by the JVM platform.

Given the edit by the OP that this is about legacy code: it seems that you want to hook into `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` for classes that are **not** part of the JVM - but that belong to your **own** code.

If that is the case, then the "answer" is simply: you have to make sure that all **your** classes are loaded by **your** class loader. The javadoc for [getResourceAsStreeam()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) clearly states:

> Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. This method delegates to this object's class loader.

Thus: learn how to use a custom classloader. Start [here](http://www.journaldev.com/349/java-classloader) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question. The main problem is that many of these ancient projects use `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` to obtain resources, but in the new environment, these resources do not exist and are redirected to other places

Comment: See my updated answer then. And just in case you consider accepting my answer ... feel free to wait until tomorrow with that ;-)

Comment: Thanks again.I tried it, it's works with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(String)`. But it's not work within `Class.class.getResourceAsStream(String)` / `String.class.getResourceAsStream(String)`

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception for attempts to define classes with a qualified name starting with `java.`, is part of [the contract of `defineClass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-), but that’s irrelevant. Any attempt to define a class with the name of an existing class on a `ClassLoader` can only have one of two possible results:

1. If the existing class has been defined by the same `ClassLoader`, attempting to define it again will be rejected and an exception will be thrown. `defineClass` does not change existing classes, that’s simply not within its functionality.
2. If the existing class has been loaded by a different `ClassLoader` (or the bootstrap loader), you may define a class with the same qualified name on this `ClassLoader`, but it will be an entirely different class, unrelated to the class with the same name but a different defining class loader.

The fact that you can not define such classes with the same name and a different loader for `java.*` classes is just an additional limitation, but your attempt wouldn’t work anyway.

If you want to replace the class `ClassLoader` after it has been loaded, you can only use an Agent, e.g. a Java Agent using the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), or a debugger. Alternatively, you can simply add your own version to the bootstrap class path using the `-Xbootclasspath/p:…` command line option.

Of course replacing it with a specific version only works in the environment, from which this version has been derived. Also such applications are not allowed to be publicly deployed.

A more general solution would be an Instrumentation Agent using the current version of `ClassLoader` and modify it on-the-fly, however, if you have to option of developing a byte code transforming Agent, it would be much easier and more reliable to transform the *application code* instead, just replacing all invocations of `Class.getResourceAsStream(String)` with an invocation of a custom method, without touching code not needing such adaptation.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a longish answer on how to implement runtime class transforms here: [how to retransform a class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18567552/how-to-retransform-a-class-at-runtime/18576798#18576798)

An easier way would be my retransformer project at https://github.com/nickman/retransformer which will transform java.* classes, including native methods. (I used it to modify Runtime.availableProcessors )