# Java Breakpoint set on java.lang.ref.Finalizer not stopped

Tags: java, debugging, java-8, jdb

I want to get some insights of Java `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` initializing process so I set a breakpoint on its class static block:

```
static {
->    ThreadGroup tg = Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup(); // breakpoint set on this line
    for (ThreadGroup tgn = tg;
         tgn != null;
         tg = tgn, tgn = tg.getParent());
    Thread finalizer = new FinalizerThread(tg);
    finalizer.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY - 2);
    finalizer.setDaemon(true);
    finalizer.start();
}
```

Then start an empty `main()` method via IntelliJ IDEA debug button, but the breakpoint never stops the program (JVM just executes to its end and exits.)

Java version:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_302"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.302.08.1 (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
```

Why this breakpoint not taking effect?

Comment: Because nothing referenced `Finalizer` so the class was never initialized.

Comment: After testing in Intellij and jdb. I found that it can't break at the static block even if we referenced `Finalizer` as `Finalizer` is loaded before main method execute. @guaner, what is the main purpose to debug `Finalizer`?

Comment: @user207421 im sure that `Finalizer` has been initialized, because a breakpoint on the empty `main()` thread stops and `jstack` shows there is a `FinalizerThread` thread waiting to do its job.

Comment: @samabcde im reading the `Finalizer` code to get a deeper understanding of JVM's `finalize()` mechanism. Then I think maybe a step by step debugging helps understanding it more smoothly so i just tried. But unfortunately, it doesn't stop...

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214174/how-is-the-java-bootstrap-classloader-loaded), `Finalizer` in `java.lang` is loaded by bootstrap class loader, which is not a java class, this seems to be the reason we can't debug.

Comment: @samabcde but some other classes in `java.lang` can be debugged like `Boolean`... maybe I think it's related to the time when `-agentlib:jdwp` kicks in?

Comment: I mean the static initialisation block can't be debugged, as it runs before main. `Boolean` doesn't have static initialisation block.

Comment: When I run an empty class with `-verbose:class`, the class `Finalizer` is the 38th class to be reported, out of over 400 classes loaded before the main class. Obviously, that’s very early and likely too early to be debuggable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JDK 5.0, the JVM debugging capability has been constructed based on [JVM TI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) which replaces the JVMPI and JVMDI. I'm not familiar with JVMDI thus the following statements are based on the fact you debug the code using `agentlib:jdwp` like:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
```

The jdwp agent (loaded from `libjdwp.so` file) bind the port specified (5005 in the above example) on receiving `post_vm_initialized` event. As the event name indicates, **VM has been initialized and the `Finalizer` class has already been loaded when the debug port binding happens** (of course you can only debug Java codes after JDWP port listening). So you cannot debug the static block code of `Finalizer`. In fact, classes loaded before JDWP port binding all are not debuggable in terms of initialization. But if thread runs in the code of the loaded-before classes afterwards, you're still able to debug it, for example the  `Finalizer.FinalizerThread#run` method.

I found a quote from [The JVM Tool Interface (JVM TI): How VM Agents Work](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/jvm-tool-interface.html):

> The library is loaded before the VM has initialized, allowing the agent library to capture early VM events that it could not access before.

JDWP agentlib may bind the port on the other hand in `Agent_Onload` function (in `debugInit.c`), which may allow the debugging for all classes loading in JVM (I guess).

PS: if you are interested in the code mentioned above (in OpenJDK 8 with Mercurial ID dcb218f54ca1):

1. `post_vm_initialized` event processing in function `debugInit.c:initialize`.
2. JDWP's `Agent_Onload` function also locates in code file `debugInit.c`.