# Java ServletContextEventHandler and static block

Tags: java, servlets

Both ServletContextEventHandler and static block have high startup priority. In usage, what is the difference? What should be put in the SC event handler and the static block?

Thanks
Ming

Comment: The `static` code block will be executed when loading the class, so it will be executed first. It would be better if you post a real specific sample of what you're trying to achieve instead of just asking. Note that this can be easily proven with `System.out.println` on both cases.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the lifecycle of classes and objects.

A `static` block is executed when a class is loaded and this more or less depends on the `ClassLoader`  your application is using. In a `static` context you only have access to other `static` components.

An object of type `ServletContextEventHandler`, by which I assume you mean `ServletContextListener`, is a hook that you can use to access your application's `ServletContext` when it is initialized and when it is destroyed.

Comment: For more info about how class loaders work in java, refer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11395074/1065197 and other links in the net like http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html and http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html

Comment: And one more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html