# How glassfish domains are separated from each other?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

GlassFish allows creating N domains. Every domain has its own Java classes (libraries etc) and system settings.

For example, we have two domains - domain1 and domain2.

Via GF web console (http://localhost:4848) one system property was set for domain1 - `com.temp.foo=test1`. Besides via GF web console (http://localhost:7575) one system property was set for domain2 - `com.temp.foo=test2`.

Now, in domain1

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.temp.foo"))
//returns `test1`
```

And in domain2

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("org.temp.foo"))
//returns `test2`
```

As I understand GF and all its domains are running in one instance of JVM. And I don't understand how it is possible in one instance of JVM separate system properties. Could anyone explain?

Note: I understand that it can be a very long explanation that's why I am asking only about main principle and solutions/libraries names in an order I could read about them on the internet.

Comment: I got some comments for my answer; and I am not so sure any more if it is really correct. I updated it; but I don't mind if you decide to un-accept. I am even considering to put up a bounty on this question ... let me know if you are interested in that.

Comment: @GhostCat Thank you for informing. If you can, please, start a bounty - this question is still important and interesting for me.

Comment: Bounty is out there!

Comment: Well ... My opinion: It first looked as if the class loading mechanism is the answer to this question. But now I second it. But that means that the system property must be the same for a single JVM. I see two possible causes of the behavior: 1) The idea of "GF and all its domains are running in one instance of JVM" might be wrong. Maybe they are two JVMs. _(I prefer this.)_ 2) Somewhere in the code the system property is overwritten prior to getting read in another place (unlikely, I think).

Comment: Too bad; I had hoped the bounty would result in some more upvotes around here ... hopefully you will at least make the "10" count ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the understanding "GF and all its domains are running in one instance of JVM" is wrong.

As per GlassFish current version's [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/administration-guide.pdf) (chapter 3):

> A domain contains a group of GlassFish Server instances that are administered
>   together. [...] A GlassFish Server instance is a single Virtual Machine for the Java platform (Java
>   Virtual Machine or JVM machine) on a single node in which GlassFish Server is
>   running.

That means, *every single instance of any domain is running in its own JVM*! As a consequence, they all could have their own different system properties.

To be fair: There are means for administering *virtual servers* in GlassFish, that seem to share a JVM, but I think you are not speaking about them.

Comment: So, here we go. I had hoped that the bounty would result in some more upvotes for all content here ... not just the question itself. But whatever ...

Comment: Could you say - one jvm is created for one domain (one jvm for domain1, one jvm for domain2) or one jvm is created for every virtual server (one jvm for domain1-virtserver1, one jvm for domain1-virtserver2, one jvm for domain2-virtserver1, one jvm for domain2-virtserver2 etc)?

Answer (score 2):

Products such as GlassFish, JBoss, WebSphere, ... "simply" make use of the Java *class loading* mechanism to create isolation. By using multiple class loaders, even a **static** class fields could exist "more than once"; and each "domain" gets its very special version of that.

Start reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/6nmndgmhp/index.html), or [there](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1752/beadg/index.html) for example:

> Application Universe – Each Java EE application has its own class loader universe, which loads the classes in all the modules in the application.

And beyond that, look into [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ghcjc.html).

In other words: although the System class obviously represents a "system view" - the class loading mechanism should make it possible to give **different** System class instances to each domain. Thereby making it possible to have domain-specific properties within each domain-specific System class. But to be precise: I could not find clear evidence to back up this statement. On that topic, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908903/scope-of-the-java-system-properties) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395074/what-loads-the-java-system-classloader) should help (the later one indicating that there even ways to tamper with the *system* classloader).

But thinking further, there is a problem with that idea: there are actually *two* class loading mechanisms. There "system/user" class loaders ... and the initial bootstrap classloader.

And the bootstrap classloader is actually "baked" into the JVM (it is implemented in native code for example) - and it can't be *replaced*.

And java.lang.System should be loaded by that bootstrap classloader!

So it is **impossible** to use "classloader magic" to enable "per domain" System properties!

The other option I see is to create a Java agent that intercepts calls and manipulates their result (see [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/) as starting point).

But again; agents come "after" bootstrapping has completed!

So the only logical conclusion (taking what is left after excluding all options): the premise of the question must be wrong!

It is simply **impossible** that different "applications" running on the **same** JVM give different system properties. And luckily, the great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44673838/how-glassfish-domains-are-separated-from-each-other/44758855#44758855) by Seelenvirtuose confirms that conclusion.

Comment: Although you are right, OP is speaking about _system properties_. And these are usually VM wide. Your "answer" does not address this.

Comment: "The class loading mechanism still makes it possible to give different System class instances to each domain." => Do you have any proof for that? I mean ... it sounds right (and I do not know enough to second it), but some validation documents would be nice. (The anser might be correct, though ...) I ask, because looking at the source code for the `System` class shows that there are some very low level native startup behaviors.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose As you suspected, the statement made by @GhostCat is false. Only the boot classloader is permitted to define classes in the `java.*` namespace, which includes `java.lang.System`. Therefore there can only be one `System` class loaded in the whole JVM. This is documented in the JavaDoc for the `ClassLoader#defineClass` method, which states that a SecurityException be thrown 'if an attempt is made to define a class in a package with a fully-qualified name that starts with "`java.`"'.