# java what does bootstrapping mean in a java context?

Tags: java

I have been working on an address book program where users details are stored so you can look up users, add users modify, etc... one of the requirements of the project, however, is to "bootstrap default users in the main method". From googling what bootstrapping is it seems like some sort of class loader to load certain classes to memory first, how would that work for default users in a command-line system? Any input on this will help greatly

Comment: "*one of the requirements of the project is to*" So speak to the person who gave you the requirements. That's what you would do in the real world of software development if you someone gave you confusing requirements. Don't ask strangers on the internet to make guesses for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What loads the java system classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11395074/what-loads-the-java-system-classloader)

Comment: In the context of your project, I doubt "bootstrap" has anything to do with class loaders. My guess is your application is supposed to have one or more "built-in", default users that you create in the main method (without any end-user input). However, you should follow Michael's advice and ask the person who gave you the requirements for clarification—they know what they meant.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I will do that. I just wondered if anybody else ever had anything like this to do before

Comment: "bootstrap" as a general term refers to making something out of nothing; we bootstrap a computer into a running system from a condition of having no program at all by loading a small program which loads a larger program which...;  we bootstrap a compiler into existence by writing a small compiler which we use to write a larger version of the compiler which we use to...