# Play: ClassLoader cannot find my class

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, java-8

I'm using Play for Java and I tried this in my Application.java

```
    // The name of the class to search
    String className = "my.fake.company.SuperGreatClass";
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("", new SubTypesScanner(false));

    // All classes
    Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);

    for (Class c : allClasses){
        String cName = c.getName();
        // Find the class that matches the name to the one we are looking for
        if (cName.contains(className))
            play.Logger.info(cName); // It always succeeds and logs the name correctly
    }

    ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    try {
        Class clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
        Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        play.Logger.error("NOT FOUND: " + e.getMessage());
        return badRequest("Cannot find that super great class of yours!");
    }
```

The reflections part correctly identifies my class, but the ClassLoader does not. Unfortunately, I use a third party library that uses the second approach and I cannot change it.

Is there something I can do to change the behaviour of the ClassLoader? I have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380275/replacement-system-classloader-for-classes-in-jars-containing-jars) but I am not sure if this will work.

The log output is:

```
2016-02-19 16:00:17 +0200 [INFO ] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 -  - my.fake.company.SuperGreatClass
2016-02-19 16:00:18 +0200 [ERROR] from application in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 -  - NOT FOUND: my.fake.company.SuperGreatClass
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a read about classloaders hierarchy in Java and the contract they follow.  [This article is one of many describing the loaders hierarchy](https://sites.google.com/site/sureshdevang/java-classloader-hierarchy)

In your code you ask **System Classloader** to load your class.  That means that It will only be **Bootstrap** and **System** classloaders being queried for your class.

To increase the search area simply invoke

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```

... which should return your class.

Comment: Yeah, I should have specified it. The exception is thrown at the "classLoader.loadClass" command and it's a class not found exception.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! I'm editing the answer as I missed something obvious.